# Script raises HTTPError, but cannot catch

Tags: python, exception

I have an error which I have a little difficulty understanding. I have a script which uses biopython to query a database. Sometimes, biopython can't find what we're looking for, and an HTTPError is thrown. I cannot, however catch the HTTPError, as I get the following error message:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        51             UniProt = text[index+9:index+15]
>        52             uniprot_IDs[bigg_ID] = UniProt
>   ---> 53         except HTTPError:
>        54             if err.code == '404':
>        55                 uniprot_IDs[biGG_ID] = None
>
> NameError: name 'HTTPError' is not defined

How can an error which is not defined be thrown in the first place? What am I missing?

This is the relevant code:

```
from Bio.KEGG import REST, Enzyme
from DataTreatment import openJson, write
```

...

```
try:
    ec_number = some_string
    text = REST.kegg_get('ec:'+ec_number).read()
```

...

```
except HTTPError:
    if err.code == '404':
        a_dict[a_key] = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the HTTPError-class, try this;

In the top of your code, add

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
```

Source: [Entrez._HTTPError vs. Entrez.HTTPError (via Entrez.efetch)](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/343)

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the HTTPError class. If you already imported, then make sure you got the right one. You can try to catch with a generic Exception and use type(ex) to find out which it is and import the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpError` is also a part of `googleapiclient.errors`

One practice to identify the source of error is to capture the type of exception. The following code can be used for it

```
try:
    # < main code here >
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

The output of this can look like

```
<class 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'>
```

With this, you will need to adjust accordingly. eg.

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
try:
    # < main code here >
except HttpError as error:
    pass
```